# how could we find the solution of this particular differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this differential equation:

$$xy'+y=y'(1-x^2y^2)^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\sin^{-1}(xy)$. Then by the chain rule

$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\sin^{-1}(xy)\Big)=\frac{(xy)'}{\sqrt{1-(xy)^2}}=\frac{xy'+y}{\sqrt{1-x^2y^2}}$$

so that

$$xy'+y=y'{\sqrt{1-x^2y^2}}$$

hence $y=\sin^{-1}(xy)$ is an implicit solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=xy$, then $\frac{du}{dx}=xy'+y$. So we get
$$
\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx} \sqrt{1-u^2},\\
\frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} dx=\frac{dy}{dx} dx,\\
\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\int dy,\\
\arcsin u=y+C,\\
\arcsin xy=y+C,\\
xy=\sin (y+C),
x=\frac{\sin (y+C)}{y}.
$$